# Kendo UI Web: Scrolling is bucking with multiline text

Tags: web, grid, scroll, kendo-ui, multiline

I have a problem with my Kendo UI web grid. As soon there is multiline text in my grid, scrolling doesn't work as it should. When I scrolling down with mouse wheel or scroll bar it doesn't scroll smooth and judders.

I'm using virtual scrolling with a xml datasource, everything goes well as long there is enough space for the text. As soon it begins to wrap i get this problem.

Here in this video you can see what i mean: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Q9CdsS1C24

```
$("#table").kendoGrid({
    sortable: true,
    selectable: "row",
    dataSource: {
       serverPaging: true,
       serverSorting: true,
       pageSize: 50,
       transport: {
           read: {
                url: gurl,
                dataType: "xml"
               }
       },
       schema: {
           type: "xml",
               data: "/response/update/tabelle/satz",
               total: "/response/update/anzahl/text()",
               model: {
                   fields: {
                       anschrift: "anschrift/text()"
           }
           }
       }
    },
    scrollable: {
       virtual: true
    },
    columns:[ {
        field: "anschrift"
    }]          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You mess the logic of the virtual scrolling when there are rows which height is more than a regular row. There is nothing you can do except to try to keep these rows with normal height.